# Want to share only the MUSIC folder with the other users and not HOME folder completely

Tags: server, permissions, login, samba, music

I created a new user "Others" so that they can login into it and use other than mine (admin). But, I want them to use the Music folder which is present in my home/vinny_ab28 (admin). I logged in to the "Others" account and accessed my admin folders using

```
others@pheonix:~$ cd /home/vinny_ab28
```

And when I typed `ls` I was able to go through all my files and folders.

So from my admin account 'vinny_ab28' I did

```
vinny_ab28@pheonix~: sudo chmod 700 /home/vinny_ab28
```

So that no one will be able to enter it.

Now I want to share the MUSIC folder which is in `/home/vinny_ab28/Music` with other users too so that they can use an play those files from my account without accessing other folders and files.

**Note: Even tried 'Local Network Sharing'. I was unable to access still.**

What can I do?

Comment: what about using soft links?